# Can someone explain me “darum, daran” and other words with ‘da’

Tags: word-usage, adverb, particle

Ich habe schon einen Sprachkurs gemacht, aber trotzdem finde ich es schwierig, viele Sachen zu verstehen. Kann mir jemand *darum, daran* und andere Wörter mit *da-* erklären (z.B. „ich bin **gerade daran**…“ habe ich oft gehört)?

It would be great if someone can give me an example in English.

Vielen Dank

Comment: I'm voting close as too broad because this is an entire grammar topic. Here's a link that might help: https://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2012/06/19/da-words-meaning-german/

Comment: @Emanuel I agree even if i gave some kind of answer!

Comment: thanks guy for your reply,well it was my first question here. please tell me where should i ask these kind of questions ? i mean which category they should fall into ?

Comment: You should try to break it down into bit sized bits. If you're looking for a more general treatment, then just type it into Google. There are plenty of attempts at explaining these things. You could read some of them and then come back here with the things you didn't understand. Also, you can try out the search here (though it sucks a bit). There are certainly some questions dealing with these things here.

Comment: @emanuel : thanks for advise ,will surely keep in mind next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here some examples:

**Dabei sein:

Dran sein (daran adapted)**

... means that you are about to do:

- Ich bin gerade dabei etwas zu kochen

I'm just cocking something

- As an Answer: Was ist mit Projekt X? Ich bin gerade dabei /dran ...
  What about Project X) I'm just ...
- Ich sitze gerade dran/daran

I'm just working on it!

**Other meanings:**

An etwas dran bleiben: 
to stay tuned

Sie kommen dran: 
It's your turn

Ich bin zu spät dran: 
I'm too late (expresses: to run late)

Durch diese Situation sind wir schlecht dran (schlecht dran sein): 
Because of this situation we are badly off

schlimmer dran sein: to be worse off

übel dran sein: to be in a bad way!

**Darum** : can be used to express: "Because, therefore..." ist used to justify!

...Darum habe bin ich zuspät gekommen

...That's why i came too late

...Darum habe ich mich nicht gemeldet (Telephon).

...That's why i didn't call!

**Other meanings:**
jemanden darum bitten etwas zu tun: to ask so. to do sth.

Alles darum geben, etwas zu haben: to give one's eye teeth for sth.

Alles darum geben etwas zu tun: to give one's eye teeth to do sth.

Es handelt sich darum, dass ... /Es geht darum: the question is if ..../ The point is ...

darum geht's doch gerade: that's just the point

Er kümmert sich keinen Deut darum: He doesn't care a straw.

Darum handelt es sich nicht: That's not the issue.

Ich werde mich sofort darum kümmern: I'll see to it at once.

Kümmere dich nicht darum!: Don't bother about it!

Bitte kümmern Sie sich darum, während ich fort bin!: Please see to this while I'm away!

...